# r.createRoot is not a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

when i deploy personal project react js  go up netlify! help me.thank!
my file index.js:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { store } from "./redux/store";
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
   </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

library in package.json:
"dependencies": {
"@emotion/react": "^11.10.6",
"@emotion/styled": "^11.10.6",
"@mui/icons-material": "^5.11.16",
"@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.127",
"@mui/material": "^5.12.1",
"@mui/styles": "^5.12.0",
"@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.4",
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
"@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
"@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
"axios": "^1.3.5",
"classnames": "^2.3.2",
"env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
"formik": "^2.2.9",
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
"react-redux": "^8.0.5",
"react-router-dom": "^6.10.0",
"react-scripts": "5.0.1",
"react-slick": "^0.29.0",
"react-toastify": "^9.1.2",
"slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
"styled-components": "^5.3.9",
"web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
"yup": "^1.1.1"
},

hope every one can help me !

Comment: how did you package it?

Comment: Does the code work locally? What version of React is installed?

Comment: yub, normal the code work locally. it's version 18.2.0

Comment: Sounds like we're your installing is still on React versions less than 18

Comment: Please add the full error message, and the version of React

Comment: full error:   Uncaught TypeError: r.createRoot is not a function
    at index.js:9:14
    at index.js:21:1
    at index.js:21:1

Comment: my version of react: 
     "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",

Comment: You could try deleting the node_modules directory and re-run npm install, just in case it's not installed correctly.